# Need matching digits between two decimals

Tags: python, decimal, matching, digits

let's say I have 2 decimals(float).

```
a = 123.62903
b = 123.6233
```

now I want the result to matching digits of this decimal. so result here should be

> 123.62.

If,

```
a =234.2387
b =232.2138
```

then, the result should be

> result = 23.

It would be a great help thank you.

Comment: what should be the output for a = 112.6 and b = 212.6? no match or 12.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip` and a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
a = 123.62903
b = 123.62333

res = ''
for i, v in zip(str(a), str(b)):
    if i != v:
        break
    else:
       res += v

if res:
    print(float(res) if "." in res else int(res))
```

**Output:**

```
123.62
```

Comment: What if first digits aren't matching but subsequent digits match?

Comment: for example a =2234.2387 b =1232.2138, here first digits aren't matching but next few matches. In this case.

Comment: And earlier there was a chance of getting no match at all, which may lead to error. You solved it and edited. Good work !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in O(1), math is your friend. :-)

```
import math

def common(a, b):
    def trunc(x, precision):
        return math.floor(x / precision) * precision
    precision = math.pow(10, math.ceil(math.log10(math.fabs(a - b))))
    common = trunc(a, precision)
    if common == trunc(b, precision):
        return common
    else:
        return trunc(a, precision * 10)

print(common(123.62903, 123.6233))
print(common(234.2387, 232.2138))
print(common(123.62903, 112.21))
```

This outputs:

```
123.62
230.0
100.0
```

Comment: It prints 2000.0 for numbers a = 2123.62903 b = 1123.6233

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it by replacing `int` with `math.ceil`.

Comment: Good. But I think still there is an error. for a = 1123.62903 b = 2123.6233 it raises error ValueError: math domain error

Comment: I guess you have to keep a as largest among both

Comment: if a=123.62903 and b = 112.xx 
Expected result = 1. but this one is giving 120

Comment: @karthikreddy Hmm the precision of the difference between two numbers may be one magnitude off indeed. I've added a condition to my code to fall back to one higher magnitude if that happens. Should work well now.

Comment: @Mufeed Indeed. I'm now using the absolute value of the difference instead then.